# Selenium Webdriver - Java - Verify partial text display with three dots at the end

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following text is displayed in a webpage.

[image: screenshot]

The HTML code is as follows -

```
<tr>
  <td valign="middle" align="left">
    <div 
      class="ellipsis" 
      style="max-width: 425px; display: inline-block;">
      HKCR\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnop
   </div>
 </td>
```

Using Selenium WebDriver with Java, I want to check that only partial text is displayed with 3 dots at the end.
From the HTML code, I'm only able to see the full text

```
HKCR\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnop
```

instead of partial text with 3 dots at the end. 
When I wrote the following code, it outputs the full text instead of partial text with 3 dots.

```
String text1 = webDriver.findElement(
  By.xpath(".../tr/td[1]")
).getText();
```

So, I'm confused as to how to verify that only partial text is actually displayed. 
Can someone please help?

Comment: That's the html. Nothing to do with selenium

Comment: Please clear the question once again ... Do you want to get the text  printed in the console with '..' in the end OR do you want to verify that your text contains  '..' in the end?

Comment: I want to verify that only partial text with 3 dots is displayed at the end

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that Selenium detects "visibility" in a way that doesn't capture text overflow hidden by ellipsis. Visibility is looking the absence of a set of criteria, [listed here in the webdriver specs](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webdriver/raw-file/tip/webdriver-spec.html#determining-if-an-element-is-displayed), and the CSS property/value "text-overflow: ellipsis" is not one.

You can still test that the elements on your page are using this CSS property. Use Selenium to verify that the divs you want have the CSS text-overflow value you want them to have with .getCssValue(), for example,

```
String cssvalue = Login.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ccleaner_options_exclude_div']/table/tbody/tr/td/div")).getCssValue("text-overflow");
```

and check that the value is "ellipsis". As long as that value is set, in theory, the browser should be truncating the text and adding an ellipsis before it overflows!

Comment: Funny, when I check in the inspector I see `ellipsis`, but this function retrieves `clip` (which is actually absent from the DOM). I wonder why.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code and reply

```
String text1 = Login.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[ends-with(@title,'...')]")).getText();
```

Comment: Hi Rupesh, I get the following error when I used your code -  org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //div[ends-with(@title,'...')] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Comment: Try below xpath                                               //div[@*[ends-with(.,'...')]]

Comment: Hi Rupesh - I get the same error when I used the above code - org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //div[@*[ends-with(.,'...')]] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a random guess. It should be a comment.